# Rails3 AJAX Error - undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I'm getting the below error when using jquery ui slider while update via ajax:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class):
1: $("#x_stock_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@date_range)) %>");
app/views/home/index.js.erb:1:in`_app_views_home_index_js_erb__1074827181885368454_2504361900'
```

My jquery slider function looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#x_slider" ).slider({
    range: true,
    step: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 52,
    values: [1, 52 ],
    stop: function(event, ui) {
       var url_param = $('#x_slider').slider('option', 'values');
       $('#x_low_selected').html(ui.value);      
       $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         data: ({ weeks: url_param[0] }),
         url: $(this).attr('data-href'),
         dataType: 'script'
       });
     }
   });
 });
</script>
```

In my home controller, I have this:

```
 def index
    unless params[:weeks]
      @date_range = 4
    else
      @date_range = Home.filter(params[:weeks])
    end
  end
```

And in my model:

```
  def self.filter(weeks)
    timeago = weeks.to_i
  end
```

Finally, in my index.js

```
 $("#x_stock_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@date_range)) %>");
```

When I drag the slider, the value is displayed fine:

```
 Parameters: {"weeks"=>"8", "_"=>"1327514933685"}
```

However it throws that error.

If I manually navigate the url http://localhost:3000/?weeks=9 everything works fine.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [render](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Rendering/render) method is not necessary here it's purpose is to render partials, files or text.  You are passing the number 4.

You don't need to [escape_javascript](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) for a number either as it expects a class that responds to gsub.

```
#From the above link:    
result = javascript.gsub(%r(\\|<\/|\r\n|\3342\2200\2250|[\n\r"'])/) {|match| JS_ESCAPE_MAP[match] }
javascript.html_safe? ? result.html_safe : result
```

Either use:

```
$("#x_stock_list").html("<%= @date_range %>");
```

Or convert it to a string:

```
$("#x_stock_list").html("<%= @date_range.to_s %>");
```

For highcharts in the past, I have done something along the lines of:

```
$.getJSON('traffic_sources.json', null, function(data) {
    pie_chart("traffic_sources_graph", data.traffic_sources);
});

function pie_chart(div, data)
{
   new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: div,
         backgroundColor: '#dddddd'
      },
       series: [{
         type: 'pie',
         name: 'Browser share',
         data: data
      }]
   });
}
```

Comment: That makes sense - have changed but now throws "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gsub' for 11:Fixnum):" ?! Weird

Comment: Yeah, you don't need the escape_javascript either.

Comment: Ok, removed to_i and that fixed but I need to refresh my view as well - I have a js graph which needs reloading to reflect the change. S

Comment: What graphing library are you using, most of them have a rerender function available.

Comment: Highcharts - currently it sits in a js function - data: <%= radacct_sessions_chart_series(radacct_sessions, @date_range.weeks.ago) %> I thought I could refresh the div it was in but might check the rerender function out... S

Comment: Ok, so does that mean using getJSON elimates the need to refresh things? Thanks for help btw. Am a little confused by the example though - not sure how to implement?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7056/discussion-between-gazler-and-simonmorley)